# Why cannot generate static Binary with GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am trying to compile may code on ubuntu with GCC and I want to run the code as standalone one this is the compiling:

```
$ gcc -static-libstdc++  main.c -o Server1    `mysql_config --cflags --libs` -lssl -lcrypto  -lm -L /user-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Then to verify the output id it is static or not I run the command below:

```
$ ldd Server1
```

leads to the output below:

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffce75e0000)
    libmysqlclient.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.20 (0x00007fbd8662f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbd86412000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbd86209000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fbd85fa0000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fbd85b45000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbd8577b000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fbd85561000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbd8535d000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbd84fda000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbd84cd1000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbd84abb000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005584efccf000)
$
```

So why the above lib not included in the Server1 Binary file?

Kinds

Comment: Did you try passing `-static` ?

Comment: Many Thanks! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To compile a standalone program using gcc, you need to use the `-static` flag when compiling.

For instance:

`gcc -static -o a.out main.c -lm`

In your case, you are trying to link your executable to shared libraries. You will need static versions of these libraries to reach your goal, otherwise `ld` will fail.